# File transfer using XMPP (Extension XEP-0065)

Tags: ios, xmpp, openfire, xmppframework

Not sure why I am getting turn socket failed (turnSocketDidFail called). Anybody can help me in figure out this? Please point me what am I doing wrong here. I know there are lots of question like this and I have already checked all of these and from that I have taken little help already. One of client is Spark and other is simulator.

**Settings:**
Server: testXyz
Senderjid: user1@testXyz
Receiverjid: user2@testXyz

```
XMPPJID *jid = [XMPPJID jidWithString:Receiverjid];
[TURNSocket setProxyCandidates:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:Receiverjid, nil]];
TURNSocket *turnSocket = [[TURNSocket alloc] initWithStream:self.chatManager.xmppStream toJID:jid];
[turnSocket startWithDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
```

**Console logs**

```
SEND: 
<iq type="get" to="Receiverjid" id="C15C428D-6007-4B4E-96D5-65F7A307121A"><query xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#items"/></iq>

RECV:
<iq xmlns="jabber:client" type="result" id="C15C428D-6007-4B4E-96D5-65F7A307121A" from="Receiverjid" to="Senderjid/4840c8ae">
<query xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#items">
<item jid="Receiverjid" node="http://jabber.org/protocol/tune"/>
<item jid="Receiverjid/Spark 2.6.3"/>
</query>
</iq>

SEND: 
<iq type="get" to="Receiverjid" id="A4D8B427-B323-4152-8B19-7B55164E9C4B">
<query xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info"/>
</iq>

RECV: 
<iq xmlns="jabber:client" type="result" id="A4D8B427-B323-4152-8B19-7B55164E9C4B" from="Receiverjid" to="Senderjid/4840c8ae">
<query xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info">
<identity category="account" type="registered"/>
<identity category="pubsub" type="pep"/>
<feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info"/>
</query>
</iq>

SEND: 
<iq type="get" to="Receiverjid/Spark 2.6.3" id="2DE55487-9203-4266-A559-1B1D3DC5FBF4">
<query xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info"/>
</iq>

RECV:
<iq xmlns="jabber:client" id="2DE55487-9203-4266-A559-1B1D3DC5FBF4" to="Senderjid/4840c8ae" type="result" from="Receiverjid/Spark 2.6.3">
<query xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info">
<identity category="client" name="Smack" type="pc"/>
<feature var="http://www.xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0166.html#ns"/>
<feature var="urn:xmpp:tmp:jingle"/>
</query>
</iq>

RECV:
<iq xmlns="jabber:client" id="2DE55487-9203-4266-A559-1B1D3DC5FBF4" to="Senderjid/4840c8ae" type="result" from="Receiverjid/Spark 2.6.3">
<query xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info">
<identity category="client" name="Smack" type="pc"/>
<feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/xhtml-im"/>
<feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/muc"/>
<feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/bytestreams"/>
<feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/commands"/>\
<feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/si/profile/file-transfer"/>
<feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/si"/>
<feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/ibb"/>
</query> 
</iq>
```

**Update**

If I am changing:

`[TURNSocket setProxyCandidates:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:Receiverjid, nil]];`

to:

`[TURNSocket setProxyCandidates:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:Server, nil]];`

It gives me:

`<error code="503" type="cancel"><service-unavailable xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas"/></error>`.

As suggested in one of question on stack to resolve this error I have replaced Receiverjid: 'user2@testXyz' by 'user2@testXyz/spark' but am still getting same error.

Comment: As per my knowledge XEP-0065 alone not able to transfer file, you need to use XEP-0096 as well to get the session ID. To transfer file session ID is main important part. Make sure session id be remain same for file transfer session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know what to set in setProxyCandidates, but I am setting my Server name.

`<error code="503" type="cancel"><service-unavailable xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas"/></error>`

**Solution:** Pass full jabber id:*username@domain/resource.*
In my case I have changed 'user2@testXyz/spark; to 'user2@testXyz/Spark 2.6.3'

I don't know how to find these resource parameters. I have checked XMPPJID class's resource parameter but it is nil. I found these parameters by seeing some console logs. If anybody know  how to find this from any xmpp class then please let me know.

Comment: While Resgistering into openfire server using XEP-0077 InbandReg pass resource as well alongwith JID.

Comment: @lducool are you able to solve the question ? if yes then please share solution because i am also facing the same issue .

Comment: I have passed full id with resource then also I am getting same error as followed. <iq xmlns="jabber:client" type="error" id="3A4379BB-8AB8-463F-AECE-4A13B8175550" from="spatil@192.168.2.120" to="jsojitra@192.168.2.120/dd985bae"><query xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/bytestreams" sid="3A4379BB-8AB8-463F-AECE-4A13B8175550" mode="tcp"><streamhost jid="proxy.192.168.2.120" host="192.168.2.120" port="7777"/></query><error code="503" type="cancel"><service-unavailable xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas"/></error></iq> Can you please tell me what can be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

[TURNSocket setProxyCandidates:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:Receiverjid, nil]]; In this replace "Receiverjid" with hostname, eg:sa.com,

Answer (score 0):

iducool ,you can find full jid with resource in following method of AppDelegate.

```
- (void)xmppStream:(XMPPStream *)sender didReceivePresence:(XMPPPresence *)presence
{
    DDLogVerbose(@"%@: %@ - %@", THIS_FILE, THIS_METHOD, [presence fromStr]);

  //  NSString *presenceType = [presence type]; // online/offline
    NSString *myUsername = [[sender myJID] user];
    NSString *presenceFromUser = [[presence from] user];

    NSLog(@" Printing full jid of user %@",[[sender myJID] full]);
    NSLog(@"Printing full jid of user %@",[[sender myJID] resource]);
    NSLog(@"From user %@",[[presence from] full]);
    senderFullID=[[presence from] full];
}
```