# File Transfer using XMPPFrameWork in IOS

Tags: ios, file-transfer, xmppframework

I am working on Chat Project using `XMPPFrameWork` in IOS. Now There is a need of File Transfer.

I have searched  lots of link but no one works. currently i am using this link for file transfer :

[Using this Code For File Transfer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12153795/file-transfer-using-xmppextension-xep-0065)

but getting no sucess. Can anyone tell me about proper tutorial that how can i send file using XMPPframeWork in Ios.

Comment: As per my knowledge XEP-0065 alone not able to transfer file, you need to use XEP-0096 as well to get the session ID. To transfer file session ID is main important part. Make sure session id be remain same for file transfer session. There is no tutorial till now for file transfer through XMPP for iOS.

Comment: @Bhumeshwerkatre thanks for the comment. Can you give any Code snippet for this.

Comment: I can help you only this much, do stream intialization using XEP-0096 and then use XEP-0065 to transfer file.

Answer (score 0):

File transfers are now included in the XMPPFramework.  See an example project [here](https://github.com/nplexity/xmpp-file-transfer-demo).